# Remove Category from a Sum

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a dataset with Company Values and a Rate.

What I would like to do is Sum the Rate by company. However, for Company A, I only want to sum the Rates for Companies B, C, D (in other words, all companies except A). Similarly, for Company B, I want the sum for Companies A, C, and D (all companies but B).

I've tried a couple different ways:
`VAR SelectComp = SELECTEDVALUE(dataset[Company]) RETURN' 'CALCULATE(SUM(dataset[Rate]), dataset[Company] <> SelectComp)`

I've also tried:
`NewTable = SUMMARIZE(dataset, dataset[Company], "SUM", CALCULATE(SUM(dataset[Rate]),REMOVEFILTERS(dataset[Company])))`

The results I'm looking for with the sample data below would equate to:

```
Company  GroupedSum
A        68
B        72
C        65
D        56
```

| Company | Rate |
| --- | --- |
| A | 4 |
| A | 4 |
| A | 4 |
| A | 3 |
| A | 3 |
| A | 1 |
| B | 2 |
| B | 2 |
| B | 3 |
| B | 2 |
| B | 1 |
| B | 5 |
| C | 1 |
| C | 5 |
| C | 2 |
| C | 4 |
| C | 5 |
| C | 5 |
| D | 5 |
| D | 5 |
| D | 2 |
| D | 5 |
| D | 4 |
| D | 5 |
| D | 5 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Measure = 
VAR _visibleCompany =
    MAX ( 'Table 1'[Company] )
VAR _sum =
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( 'Table 1'[Rate] ),
        FILTER ( ALL ( 'Table 1' ), NOT 'Table 1'[Company] IN { _visibleCompany } )
    )
RETURN
    _sum
```

[image: Solution]

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let know if I missed anything.

Sum of Rate = CALCULATE(SUM('Table'[Rate]),ALL('Table'[Company]))-CALCULATE(SUM('Table'[Rate]))

Comment: That didn't work. But I used a similar tactic to solve: SUM(Table[Rate]) - CALCULATE(SUM(Table[Rate]),ALLEXCEPT(Table, Table[Company]))

Answer (score -1):

`SUM` everything and then subtract the sum of each individual company using `ALLEXCEPT`

```
SUM(Table[Rate]) - CALCULATE(SUM(Table[Rate]),ALLEXCEPT(Table, Table[Company]))
```